# Not able to highlight a word with special character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page as shown below. I want to highlight the a word with special character inside . For example, I'm searching for C# but c# is not getting highlighted, wherein other words without special character are getting highlighted. What may be the problem? I have included the jquery used for highlighting.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Example</title>
<style>
  body { min-height: 100vh;background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #74ebd5 0%, #9face6 100%); }
  .container { margin: 150px auto; max-width: 640px; font-family: 'Raleway'; line-height: 1.8;}
    .highlight {background: #FFCD69;color:#222; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 3px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>C C++ C# Java</h1>
  <h1>Java is a programming language</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
  a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <h1>Java is a programming language</h1>
  </div>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.highlight.js"></script>
  <script>

         $('.container').each(function () {
            $(this).highlight("c#",
            {
                wordsOnly: true, wordsBoundary: '\\b\\W*'
            });
        });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery.highlight.js

---

```
/*
 * jQuery Highlight plugin
 *
 * Based on highlight v3 by Johann Burkard
 * http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html
 *
 * Code a little bit refactored and cleaned (in my humble opinion).
 * Most important changes:
 *  - has an option to highlight only entire words (wordsOnly - false by default),
 *  - has an option to be case sensitive (caseSensitive - false by default)
 *  - highlight element tag and class names can be specified in options
 *
 * Usage:
 *   // wrap every occurrence of text 'lorem' in content
 *   // with <span class='highlight'> (default options)
 *   $('#content').highlight('lorem');
 *
 *   // search for and highlight more terms at once
 *   // so you can save some time on traversing DOM
 *   $('#content').highlight(['lorem', 'ipsum']);
 *   $('#content').highlight('lorem ipsum');
 *
 *   // search only for entire word 'lorem'
 *   $('#content').highlight('lorem', { wordsOnly: true });
 *
 *   // search only for the entire word 'C#'
 *   // and make sure that the word boundary can also
 *   // be a 'non-word' character, as well as a regex latin1 only boundary:
 *   $('#content').highlight('C#', { wordsOnly: true , wordsBoundary: '[\\b\\W]' });
 *
 *   // don't ignore case during search of term 'lorem'
 *   $('#content').highlight('lorem', { caseSensitive: true });
 *
 *   // wrap every occurrence of term 'ipsum' in content
 *   // with <em class='important'>
 *   $('#content').highlight('ipsum', { element: 'em', className: 'important' });
 *
 *   // remove default highlight
 *   $('#content').unhighlight();
 *
 *   // remove custom highlight
 *   $('#content').unhighlight({ element: 'em', className: 'important' });
 *
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Bartek Szopka
 *
 * Licensed under MIT license.
 *
 */

(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node/CommonJS
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery.extend({
        highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className, callback) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                var match = node.data.match(re);
                if (match) {
                    // The new highlight Element Node
                    var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
                    highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
                    // Note that we use the captured value to find the real index
                    // of the match. This is because we do not want to include the matching word boundaries
                    var capturePos = node.data.indexOf( match[1] , match.index );

                    // Split the node and replace the matching wordnode
                    // with the highlighted node
                    var wordNode = node.splitText(capturePos);
                    wordNode.splitText(match[1].length);

                    var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
                    highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
                    wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
                    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback(highlight)   
                    }
                    return 1; //skip added node in parent
                }
            } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
                    !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
                    !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === className)) { // skip if already highlighted
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className, callback);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });

    jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
        var settings = {
          className: 'highlight',
          element: 'span'
        };

        jQuery.extend(settings, options);

        return this.find(settings.element + '.' + settings.className).each(function () {
            var parent = this.parentNode;
            parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            parent.normalize();
        }).end();
    };

    jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options, callback) {
        var settings = {
          className: 'highlight',
          element: 'span',
          caseSensitive: false,
          wordsOnly: false,
          wordsBoundary: '\\b'
        };

        jQuery.extend(settings, options);

        if (typeof words === 'string') {
          words = [words];
        }
        words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
          return word != '';
        });
        words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
          return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
        });

        if (words.length === 0) {
          return this;
        };

        var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? '' : 'i';
        // The capture parenthesis will make sure we can match
        // only the matching word
        var pattern = '(' + words.join('|') + ')';
        if (settings.wordsOnly) {
            pattern =
                (settings.wordsBoundaryStart || settings.wordsBoundary) +
                pattern +
                (settings.wordsBoundaryEnd || settings.wordsBoundary);
        }
        var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

        return this.each(function () {
            jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className, callback);
        });
    };
}));
```

Comment: I haven't looked at all closely at the code you've posted, but this one part stands out: `wordsOnly: true`; given that `#` is, and most - if not all - 'special characters' are, not considered as letters it seems that looking for words only is part of the problem. Have you tried `wordsOnly: false`?

Comment: @David Thomas Yes tried `wordsOnly: false`. Problem in this case is it also highlights single characters. if i serach c it also highlights character c which is in between the words. For eg it highlights c in connection, c in process etc. i dont want it like that

Comment: Have you tried escaping the # with a backslash?

Comment: @NielsNet Yes, still not working

Comment: @Vinod I tried wordsBoundary: '[\\b\\W]' is working.

Comment: @samabcde '[\\b\\W]' in this case it compulsorily requires a special character. In my eg code after changing to this, if i search for C. It does not highlight the character c in `<h1>C C++ C# Java</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

The below code snippet shows effect by configuring different `wordBoundary`.

```js
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery.extend({
    highlight: function(node, re, nodeName, className, callback) {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var match = node.data.match(re);
        if (match) {
          // The new highlight Element Node
          var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
          highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
          // Note that we use the captured value to find the real index
          // of the match. This is because we do not want to include the matching word boundaries
          var capturePos = node.data.indexOf(match[1], match.index);

          // Split the node and replace the matching wordnode
          // with the highlighted node
          var wordNode = node.splitText(capturePos);
          wordNode.splitText(match[1].length);

          var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
          highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
          wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
          if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback(highlight)
          }
          return 1; //skip added node in parent
        }
      } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
        !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
        !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === className)) { // skip if already highlighted
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
          i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className, callback);
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
  });

  jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function(options) {
    var settings = {
      className: 'highlight',
      element: 'span'
    };

    jQuery.extend(settings, options);

    return this.find(settings.element + '.' + settings.className).each(function() {
      var parent = this.parentNode;
      parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
      parent.normalize();
    }).end();
  };

  jQuery.fn.highlight = function(words, options, callback) {
    var settings = {
      className: 'highlight',
      element: 'span',
      caseSensitive: false,
      wordsOnly: false,
      wordsBoundary: '\\b'
    };

    jQuery.extend(settings, options);

    if (typeof words === 'string') {
      words = [words];
    }
    words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i) {
      return word != '';
    });
    words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
      return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
    });

    if (words.length === 0) {
      return this;
    };

    var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? '' : 'i';
    // The capture parenthesis will make sure we can match
    // only the matching word
    var pattern = '(' + words.join('|') + ')';
    //console.log(pattern);
    if (settings.wordsOnly) {
      pattern =
        (settings.wordsBoundaryStart || settings.wordsBoundary) +
        pattern +
        (settings.wordsBoundaryEnd || settings.wordsBoundary);
    }
    //console.log(pattern);
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

    return this.each(function() {
      jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className, callback);
    });
  };
}));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/knownasilya/jquery-highlight/blob/master/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #74ebd5 0%, #9face6 100%);
    }
    
    .container .container2 .container3 {
      margin: 10px auto;
      max-width: 640px;
      font-family: 'Raleway';
      line-height: 1.8;
    }
    
    .highlight {
      background: pink;
      color: #222;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .highlight2 {
      background: #EE0000;
      color: #222;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .highlight3 {
      background: #00EE00;
      color: #222;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Using <b>\\b\\W*</b></p>
  <div class="container">
    <p>++F a C++ Java a ++D a E++</p>
    <p>Z a language</p>
    <p>++G++</p>
  </div>
  <p>Using <b>\\W*\\b</b></p>
  <div class="container2">
    <p>++F a C++ Java a ++D a E++</p>
    <p>Z a language</p>
    <p>++G++</p>
  </div>
  <p>Using Start:<b>(?:^|\\W*\\b|\\b\\W*)</b> End:<b>(?:$|\\W*\\b|\\b\\W*)</b></p>
  <div class="container3">
    <p>++F a C++ Java a ++D a E++</p>
    <p>Z a language</p>
    <p>++G++</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var searchList = ["Z",  "java","c++", "++D", "E++", "++F", "language","++G++"];
      $('.container').each(function() {
        $(this).highlight(searchList, {
          wordsOnly: true,
          wordsBoundary: '\\b\\W*'
        });
      });
      $('.container2').each(function() {
        $(this).highlight(searchList, {
          wordsOnly: true,
          className: 'highlight2',
          wordsBoundary: '\\W*\\b'
        });
      });
      $('.container3').each(function() {
        $(this).highlight(searchList, {
          wordsOnly: true,
          className: 'highlight3',
          wordsBoundaryStart: '(?:^|\\W*\\b|\\b\\W*)',
          wordsBoundaryEnd: '(?:$|\\W*\\b|\\b\\W*)'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As quote from the [API documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-highlight) of **`jquery-highlight`**

> wordsBoundary -- If wordsOnly is set to true, this is used to determine these boundaries, defaults to \b (word boundary).
>   wordsBoundaryStart -- If wordsOnly is set to true, this is used to determine prefix word boundaries, defaults to the value of wordsBoundary.
>   wordsBoundaryEnd -- If wordsOnly is set to true, this is used to determine suffix word boundaries, defaults to the value of wordsBoundary.

For `wordsBoundary \b\W*`, the search expression will become `\b\W*(target word)\b\W*`, this means
1. start with a word boundary position between word and not word character (\b),
2. followed by zero or more non word character(\W*),
3. then the target word,
4. then a word boundary position between word and not word character(\b),
5. end by zero or more non word character(\W*).

Hence the word `++D` **start** with non word character can be searched.
And for the opposite case `\W*\b(target word)\W*\b`, the word `C++` **end** with non word character can be searched.
Observe that `++F` and `E++` is not matching, ***hope someone familiar with Regex can help to explain***.

Anyway it gives a hint that combining first and second expression should be what we are looking for.  Since we need different expression in start and end, we can make use of `wordsBoundaryStart` and `wordsBoundaryEnd` options. Then using the or `|` operator to combine first and second expression, and add the begin(^) in `wordsBoundaryStart`, end($) in `wordsBoundaryEnd`, the target words will be highlighted.
Since the `highlight` method will consider the first group as the highlight target, we need to use non capturing group `(?:)` for the 'or' condition.